# How to extend passport.js module AuthenticateOptions interface

Tags: typescript, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

Passport.js strategies can support additional options in the authenticate call:

```js
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
      // Default passport options
      failWithError: true,
      successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
      // Custom option supported by the azure-ad plugin
      // Type error - 'tenantIdOrName' does not exist in type 'AuthenticateOptions'
      tenantIdOrName: 'common',
    });
```

Using an option that's supported by a custom strategy, eg `tenantIdOrName` above, results in a typescript error because it's not a part of passport's  `AuthenticateOptions` interface [found here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/91c229dbdb653dbf0da91992f525905893cbeb91/types/passport/index.d.ts#L42-L60) and used in the `authenticate` signature [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/91c229dbdb653dbf0da91992f525905893cbeb91/types/passport/index.d.ts#L71)

I've tried a few things without success

- module augmentation ie `declare module 'passport' {...}` seems to override the module's typings instead of extending them (anything not in my extension is treated as untyped)
- merging interfaces ie `declare namespace passport { interface AuthenticateOptions { ...new properties }}`, this seems to have no effect on the `authenticate` method signature.

How can I support additional properties in the `authenticate` call without type-casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to import the existing module for my module augmentation to extend the module's types.

The following in a .d.ts file* successfully extends the `AuthenticateOptions` interface:

```
import { AuthenticateOptions } from 'passport';

declare module 'passport' {
  // Extend acceptable authenticate options for Passport Azure AD
  // https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#513-options-available-for-passportauthenticate
  interface AuthenticateOptions {
    customState?: string;
    resourceURL?: string;
    tenantIdOrName?: string;
    domain_hint?: string;
    login_hint?: string;
    prompt?: string;
  }
}
```

*I found the file must *not* be named `passport.d.ts`, any other name worked fine